# Convert binary string to flags in typescript

Tags: typescript, flags, binary-operators

I have a binary string which I want to convert to the equivalent flag enum value. My attempt:

```
const permissionNum = parseInt(this.auth.decodedToken.permissions, 2);
const userPermissions: PermissionFlags = PermissionFlags[PermissionFlags[permissionNum]];
```

and this is the enum:

```
export enum PermissionFlags {
  None = 0,
  RemoveMember = 1 << 0,
  Invite = 1 << 1,
  EditArticleSettings = 1 << 2,
  CheckOut = 1 << 3,
  CheckIn = 1 << 4,
  CanView = 1 << 5,
  IsOwner = 1 << 6,
  xxx = 1 << 7
}
```

This does work as long as it is a single flag. So if the string is `00111000` this is parsed to 56 but `userPermissions`stays undefined. Is that not possible in Typescript?

Comment: What are the possible values of `PermissionFlag` enum?

Comment: I've added the Enum

Comment: What kind of runtime behavior are you expecting?  TypeScript supports `const userPermissions: PermissionFlags = permissionNum;`, since at runtime numeric enum values are just numbers.   If that doesn't suffice, please edit the code above to constitute a [mcve] demonstrating your actual use case.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums in TypeScript work a bit differently compared to those in C#. After all, they are compiled down to a simple JavaScript object with indexing based on the names and values. Therefor, that object will not contain a valid entry for the index that is the combination of multiple flags, but only for the individual flag values.

For example, your enum declaration will compile to the following JavaScript:

```js
export var PermissionFlags;
(function (PermissionFlags) {
    PermissionFlags[PermissionFlags["None"] = 0] = "None";
    PermissionFlags[PermissionFlags["RemoveMember"] = 1] = "RemoveMember";
    PermissionFlags[PermissionFlags["Invite"] = 2] = "Invite";
    PermissionFlags[PermissionFlags["EditArticleSettings"] = 4] = "EditArticleSettings";
    PermissionFlags[PermissionFlags["CheckOut"] = 8] = "CheckOut";
    PermissionFlags[PermissionFlags["CheckIn"] = 16] = "CheckIn";
    PermissionFlags[PermissionFlags["CanView"] = 32] = "CanView";
    PermissionFlags[PermissionFlags["IsOwner"] = 64] = "IsOwner";
    PermissionFlags[PermissionFlags["xxx"] = 128] = "xxx";
})(PermissionFlags || (PermissionFlags = {}));
```

If you now index into the `PermissionFlags` object with the index 56, you get `undefined` as no value is defined for that specific index.

I would rather use the approach in the following code snippet:

```js
export enum PermissionFlags {
  None = 0,
  RemoveMember = 1 << 0,
  Invite = 1 << 1,
  EditArticleSettings = 1 << 2,
  CheckOut = 1 << 3,
  CheckIn = 1 << 4,
  CanView = 1 << 5,
  IsOwner = 1 << 6,
  xxx = 1 << 7
}

export function hasPermission(userPermissions: number | string, flags: PermissionFlags): boolean {
  const perm = typeof userPermissions === "number" ? userPermissions : parseInt(userPermissions, 2);
  return (perm & flags) === flags;
}

// Check for permissions by specifying the user permission mask and the target permission flags
const canInvite = hasPermission("00111000", PermissionFlags.Invite);
const canCheckInAndIsOwner = hasPermission(56, PermissionFlags.CheckIn | PermissionFlags.IsOwner);
// Could even call it with PermissionFlags as first argument as those are basically numbers
const canCheckOut = hasPermission(PermissionFlags.CheckOut | PermissionFlags.IsOwner, PermissionFlags.CheckOut);
```

Comment: I really like this solution... sleek and versatile

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPermissions(val :number| PermissionFlags) : number[] {
var res = Object.keys(PermissionFlags)
.filter(t=> typeof t !== "number" && val & +t)
.map(t=>+t);
return res; 
}
var r = PermissionFlags.CheckIn | PermissionFlags.IsOwner;
var q = getPermissions(r);
console.log(q[0] === PermissionFlags.CheckIn)
console.log(q[1] === PermissionFlags.IsOwner)
```

Basically get the values of enum. apply has flag with "val & t" expression return the matched values. You may not want to return an array so instead you can make sth like this:

```
let flags =0;
res.forEach(r=> flags|=r);
return flags;
```

funny part of it if you know your number is valid you can directly cast it to enum.

Comment: I think your solution would work too (I have not tested it) but I go for Anon's solution since it's more sleek/elegant

Answer (score 0):

Anon answer is great but be careful, there is a security issue inside it.
the line

```
const canCheckInAndIsOwner = hasPermission(56, PermissionFlags.CheckIn | PermissionFlags.IsOwner);
```

won't do what it says, in fact it will be `canCheckInOrIsOwner`.
If you want it to be `and` and not `or`, you should replace the line :

```
return (perm & flags) !== 0;
```

by

```
return (perm & flags) === flags;
```

Comment: Thanks @macaque, you have a valid point there. I edited my answer accordingly.